# Unable to execute snowflake master procedure (calls another procedure) from ADF lookup

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure in Snowflake which calls two other stored procedures. This is getting executed in Snowflake and working successfully. I want to call this using ADF. I have already tried calling other stored procedure in ADF pipeline and they work using lookup activity.
However, it is not working for this particular master procedure. I think ADF is not able to go to the child procedures.

**Sample snowflake query:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHILD1(DBNAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
var result="";

var sql_command = `Truncate table if exists ${DBNAME}.PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE`;

snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_command});

return result;
$$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MASTER(DBNAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
var result="";

var sql_command = `CALL CHILD1(?)`;

snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DBNAME]});

return result;
$$
;
```

**ADF design:**

[image]

**Lookup query:**

```
@concat('CALL PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(',pipeline().parameters.DB_NAME,')')
```

**Passing the database name as parameter**

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error message?